# View e-mail through shared network drive

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook, shared-folders

At my company there is a limited network that does not have internet/e-mail access.  However, it does have access to a shared network drive.  I also have an always-on desk computer that has full internet/e-mail access that can write to the same network drive.  E-mail is with Microsoft Exchange, accessed using Outlook 2010.

Is there any way to configure Outlook, or another program, to allow continuous e-mail access from the limited network?  I can install programs on either computer, but not open ports, etc.  I don't care if I can't send e-mails from the limited network, but I would at least like to be notified of new e-mails and have title/sender information.

Any suggested tool/combination of tools, or should I code it myself?

Comment: Do you want to access your emails from other computers or what?

Comment: @thims - Yes, I want to view my e-mails from other computers that don't have internet access, only network drive access.